# Javascript Multiplication Calculator

Tags: javascript, html, calculator

Javascript beginner here. I've created a simple multiplication calculator. However I need Number 2 to increase Number 1 by a percent. Any assistance would be great.

Current setup: 100 x 7 = 700

Needs to be: 100 x(increased) by 7(%) = 107

```
<html>
<head>

<title>JS Calculator</title>

<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
function multiply(){
a=Number(document.calculator.number1.value);
b=Number(document.calculator.number2.value);
c=a*b;
document.calculator.total.value=c;
}
</script>

</head>

<body>

<form name="calculator">
Number 1: <input type="text" name="number1"><br>
Number 2: <input type="text" name="number2"> <br>
Get Result: <input type="text" name="total"> <br>
<input type="button" value="Multiply" onclick="javascript:multiply();">
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe what you want is:

```
c = a * (1 + (b/100.0))
```

To follow your example, this will give you 100 increased by 7%   (100 * 1.07 = 107)

Comment: @Michael, no problem!  Feel free to mark my reply as the answer if you feel it is correct! :)

Answer (score 1):

7% = 0.07 or 7/100.

```
value * (7 / 100.0);
```

or

```
value * 0.07;
```

Note that you should use 100.0 (or 7.0) so that the final number is not rounded.

In your example, I think you want:

```
c = a + (a * (b / 100.0));
```

Comment: Btw, this is a basic arithmetic question and nothing to do with javascript or HTML. :)

Answer (score 0):

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
function multiply(){
a=Number(document.calculator.number1.value);
b=Number(document.calculator.number2.value);
d = b / 100
c = a * d;
document.calculator.total.value=c;
}
</script>
```

Comment: For the sample input, this returns 7.  He wants 107.